# Select from two strings where they differ

Tags: javascript, regex

My page receives two strings:

```
var string1 = "_some_specification_ABC_DEFGH_end_code";
var string2 = "_some_specification_34_kj_w7_end_code";
```

And I want to take where they differ to display later as title

```
function selectRelevantInfo (string1, string2) {
    // I don't know if some Regex could help here
};
```

It should give **ABC_DEFGH** to *string1* and **34_kj_w7** to *string2*.

How can I achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: will the strings always have the same text before & after the unique part?

Comment: @levi Yes, they will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt, with a few tests to make sure all is well when the prefix/postfix are non-existent, or if they are both strings, etc.

It's similar in spirit to Pablo's code, in that it searches from the front and back of the strings, but rather than using `indexOf` at each iteration ([accidentally quadratic](http://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/)), it does scalar character comparisons. The function will return an object containing the prefix and postfix as well as both input strings stripped of these.

```js
function findPrePostfix(a, b) {
  var minLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

  // Important initialization and prefix search
  var preLen = minLength;
  for (var i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
      preLen = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Similar search for postfix search plus an important initialization
  var postLen = minLength - preLen;
  for (var i = 0; i < minLength - preLen; i++) {
    if (a[a.length - i - 1] !== b[b.length - i - 1]) {
      postLen = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return {
    a : a.substring(preLen, a.length - postLen),
    b : b.substring(preLen, b.length - postLen),
    prefix : a.substring(0, preLen),
    postfix : a.substring(a.length - postLen, a.length)
  };
}

function display(a, b) {
  $("body").append("<p>“" + a + "” vs “" + b + "”: <tt>" +
                   JSON.stringify(findPrePostfix(a, b)) + "</tt></p>");
}
// display = function(a, b) { console.log(findPrePostfix(a, b)) };

display('_some_specification_ABC_DEFGH_end_code',
        '_some_specification_34_kj_w7_end_code');

display("abc123", "123");
display("abc", "abc123");

display("abc", "def");
display("abc", "abc");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var i;
var start;
var end;

for (var i = string1.length; i > 0; i--) { 
    if (string2.indexOf(string1.substr(0, i)) != -1) {
        start = i;
        break;
    }
}

for (var i = start; i < string1.length; i++) { 
    if (string2.indexOf(string1.substr(i, string1.length)) != -1) {
        end =i;
        break;
    }
}

var dif1 = string1.substr(start, string1.length - end);
var dif2 = string2.substr(start, string2.length - end);
```

Of course it could be optimized to support different things, and check if there is really a difference and other stuff, but to start this could be very useful

Comment: I had need of this a few days ago and couldn't find a regexp to do the trick, so I wrote something like this too. But this algorithm is quadratic because you call `String.indexOf` on increasingly-longer strings, instead of just checking that single characters match. Can you fix this?

Comment: I don't think you could do this by regex because you don't know where to cut the string.

Comment: What I meant in my comment is, instead of `if (string2.indexOf(string1.substr(0, i)) != -1)` you could just do `if (string2[i] === string1[i])`. And similarly in the second loop.